# How to call this Delete web api method in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Delete WebAPI implemented, which is working fine and tested through swagger:

```
//Delete IVR Paycode Profiles
[System.Web.Http.HttpDelete, System.Web.Http.Route("PayCodeProfile")]
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ConfirmResponse> DeleteIVRPaycodeProfile(string profileIds)
{
    string orgoid = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["ORGOID"];
    SetContext(orgoid);
    return _implementation.DeleteIVRPaycodeProfileAsync(orgoid, profileIds);
}
```

And I am calling from client like below:

```
var endpointURL = new Uri("http://localhost/ADP.TLM.IVR/TLM/v1/IVR/PayCodeProfile/1,2,3");
var request = WebRequest.Create(endpointURL) as HttpWebRequest;
if (request != null)
{
    request.Headers.Add("ORGOID", "G344G4GEJXDJJ9M5");

    // sending comma separated string of ids like 1,2,
    // not sure if the ContentType is correct
    request.ContentType = "text/html";

    request.Method = "DELETE";

    using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        if (response != null)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConfirmResponse>(result);
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting `404:Not Found error`, I believe that somewhere I am making a mistake for `ContentType`.

Comment: Just as an aside: embed `var reader = new StreamReader` in a using statement too, just like David does in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your url. at first you need to send the request to this address: "http://localhost/ADP.TLM.IVR/TLM/v1/IVR/PayCodeProfile". then depend on your content type(by default it is json) create your request. if your content type is json try this:

```
private static T Call<T>(string url, string body, int timeOut = 60)
{
    var contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    request.Timeout = timeOut * 1000;
    request.ContentLength = contentBytes.Length;
    request.Method = "DELETE";
    request.ContentType = @"application/json";

    using (var requestWritter = request.GetRequestStream())
        requestWritter.Write(contentBytes, 0, (int)request.ContentLength);

    var responseString = string.Empty;
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        reader.BaseStream.ReadTimeout = timeOut * 1000;
        responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
}
```

then call it like this:

```
    var url = "http://localhost/ADP.TLM.IVR/TLM/v1/IVR/PayCodeProfile";
    var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { profileIds = "1,2,3" });
    var output = Call<dynamic>(url, body);
```

Comment: No David, it is not working..I am getting 405:Method not allowed at  using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse) this line.

Comment: ok. that's another problem. WebApi probably blocks the CORS request. To enable CORS on WebApi, use the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package. For further details, check http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api